# What's the difference between "firewall-cmd --reload" and "systemctl restart firewalld.service"?

Tags: firewalld, firewall-cmd

What's the difference between `firewall-cmd --reload` and `systemctl restart firewalld`?

Answer (score 5):

- `systemctl restart firewalld` will kill the process and start a new one.
- `firewall-cmd --reload` will

> The reload command drops all runtime configurations and applies a permanent configuration. [source](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/firewalls/introduction-to-firewalld-on-centos/)

Every configuration without the `--permanent` flag is a runtime configuration and

> Runtime configuration changes are not retained on reboot or upon restarting FirewallD whereas permanent changes are not applied to a running system.

As pointed out by @mircea-vutcovici reloading the firewall rules with firewall-cmd will not cause the system to use a potential new firewalld executable if it has been updated since the last restart of the daemon. However depending on your distribution that might have been done by the package manager when the package has been updated. The [documentation](https://firewalld.org/documentation/the-daemon-firewalld.html) states:

> To reload `firewalld` you can either use the command line tool `firewall-cmd --reload` or you can send the `SIGHUP` signal to `firewalld` for example with `killall -HUP firewalld`.

The `killall -HUP firewalld` step is executed when running `systemctl reload firewalld`. Looking at the basic [design](https://firewalld.org/documentation/concepts.html) of firewalld it is essentially a *frontend* to `iptables` or similar backends. So killing the firewalld process should not affect the actual firewall rules. So both ways of reloading the firewalld rules have the same effect. I would personally prefer the systemd way for the sake of making sure that the most recent firewalld executable is used.

Comment: Thank you very much so!!! Then those two have the same effect on firewalld? i.e. I can 
 use either of two always??

Comment: Reload should be a bit faster. If firewalld was upgraded, but not restarted, it will use the old binary even if you reload it. So, sometimes is better to reload other times is required to restart.

Comment: @peter-turner does that explain things?

Comment: Take into account, that all states are lost, when you restart the process. In order to avoid potential connection losses a reload should generally be preferred (that depends on your firewall configuation of cause): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateful_firewall